# What is a mnemonic in java?

Tags: java, mnemonics

I can find a bunch of info talking about mnemonics but nothing about what they are. Can someone help me here?

Comment: mnemonics are not hell!!

Comment: You mean the Swing component keyboard shortcuts? If not, no clue--you need to provide some context.

Comment: Google is your friend. I easily found a description, maybe you searched for the wrong thing?

Comment: @PicklishDoorknob Uh well I didn't.

Answer (score 9):

From [swing documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#mnemonic):

> Mnemonics offer a way to use the keyboard to navigate the menu
>   hierarchy, increasing the accessibility of programs.

It's the underlined letter in menus, buttons, labels, tabs etc. Pressing the ALT-key and the underlined letter on the keyboard selects that menu item.

Comment: Not only in menus. Labels, buttons and tabs can also have one.

Answer (score 2):

A mnemonic is a keyboard shortcut that allows you to access some menu item. It's an accessibility thing.

This [tutorial](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/guidebook/?name=JMenuBar&page=3) is a good illustration.